# Javascript Mouseover with Image

Tags: javascript

^Here’s my problem^

I want the button «Generelt» (Generally in English) to be on the same line as all the others one (Startside, Nyheter, Fakta, Medlem etc.). I didn't fint out how I do that, so my question is simple how do I do that? I also want the «Generelt»-image to be in the same size as the «Donér» (Donate) button, but when the second image comes (where you can choose page) I want it to be in the size it is now, that would say the image switch/change size when you put your mouse on the image, but I still want it all on the same line.

Here's the source in question:

```
<A HREF="default.php"
   onMouseOver="hiLite('img01','startside2')"
   onMouseOut="hiLite('img01','startside1')"><IMG SRC="startside1.gif" WIDTH="124" HEIGHT="28" BORDER="0" ALT="" NAME="img01"></A>

<A HREF="nyheter.htm"
   onMouseOver="hiLite('img02','nyheter2')"
   onMouseOut="hiLite('img02','nyheter1')"><IMG SRC="nyheter1.gif" WIDTH="87" HEIGHT="28" BORDER="0" ALT="" NAME="img02"></A>

<A HREF="fakta.htm"
   onMouseOver="hiLite('img03','fakta2')"
   onMouseOut="hiLite('img03','fakta1')"><IMG SRC="fakta1.gif" WIDTH="78" HEIGHT="28" BORDER="0" ALT="" NAME="img03"></A>

<A HREF="medlem.htm"
   onMouseOver="hiLite('img04','medlem2')"
   onMouseOut="hiLite('img04','medlem1')"><IMG SRC="medlem1.gif" WIDTH="86" HEIGHT="28" BORDER="0" ALT="" NAME="img04"></A> 

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript"><!--
document.write("<P><A HREF=\"javascript:nada()\"><IMG SRC=\""+picture_source+"\" width=124 height=76 NAME=\"img05\" border=0 USEMAP=\"#dir1\"></A>");
   //--></SCRIPT>
</SCRIPT>
<NOSCRIPT>
   <IMG SRC="generelt2.gif" WIDTH="124" HEIGHT="28" BORDER="0" USEMAP="#dir2" ALT="Directory: Home-Mail-Links">
</NOSCRIPT>
```

How would I do this?

EDIT: How would I make a display: inline-block and where should I put it? I need it so that I can have it on the same line, as said before.

Full site here: http://christofferhn.comoj.com/help.htm

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're required to post a sample of your code to ask a question. External links are not considered adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `<P>` element inside the document.write and you will probably get what you want.

I have to agree with isherwood though, the way that you are setting up your website is very non-standard and you should very much rethink it.

Comment: How would I drop the element inside the document.write? And what do you mean with non-standard? Is it anyway I can make it … ehm … standard?

Comment: Oops, it interpreted <p> as a newline (which is what it means in html).

Comment: As for the standard issue, you don't have any plain text on the page, it's all graphics. You use image maps, which I haven't seen in quite some time. If you look at stack overflow for instance, there's almost no text on the page that is not plain text (some formatting, but images are not used). The StackExchange drop down at the top and Careers 2.0 on the right are the only two examples I see of images used for text. Google is similar, other then the logo, all the text is plain text.

Comment: So how would I do it if I want the same effect, but in a more standard way and that works? Of course all on the same line. Can you please help? That would have been great! Thanks.

Comment: I got it on the same line. Just removed <P>, thanks to you. But I still have that problem that Generelt (again: Generally) must be on the same size at the second image when you put your mouse over it. I don't want Generally to change size just because the second image do.

Comment: You shouldn't use the effect, period, because no one can tell that there's anything underneath/behind it until they hover over it. That's what's known as Mystery Meat Navigation, and while you may find it nifty, your users probably won't.

Answer (score 2):

A paragraph is a block-level element, which will naturally drop to a new line. You need to use a span as a wrapper, or apply `display: inline-block` to the element you do use.

I'd reconsider your approach here. It's very non-standard, which means it'll be confusing for users, and it's probably not very accessible to those with handicaps at all.